# Type Ahead Breaks with new Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I've got a table with the type ahead feature from jQuery UI. It is working with my form when there is only 1 table row (initial view). There's a button to allow the user to create additional table rows as required, but for any additional table rows the type ahead feature no longer works.

I've setup a sample JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/9REgZ/1/

If you start typing in the first field - the Activity Type - you should start to get a list of matching words which you can select (the Risk select menu is also auto entered based on the activity that was entered). Both the typeahead list and the auto select work for the first row but when you click the New Row button they stop working for any newly created row.

Appreciate if someone can point out what's breaking and how to get around it - I'm new to Javascript at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's something](http://jsfiddle.net/9REgZ/3/) to help you move forward. When you create a new row you have to call the `autocomplete()` method to initialize the field.

Here's some of the relevant code:

```
$( '#nextYear' ).on( 'click', '#button2', function () {
    var row = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );

    row = row.clone().insertAfter( row );

    row.find( 'input[name="activity"]' ).val( '' ).attr(

      'id', "nextYearSelect" + ( row.index() + 1 )

    ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });    

});
```

Make sure that you're not ending up with duplicate `id` attribute values on different elements.

Comment: Thanks JMM - I'm working on incrementing the ID numbers first so there are no duplicates, will then see how I go using your suggestions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if you noticed, but I included some incrementing code (see the `row.index() + 1` part). If you don't particularly care what the numbers are and won't be removing rows as well as adding them, that's probably sufficient. Of course there are other ways you can solve the problem, as discussed in the new question you posted.